# Glue Job processing JSON to Parquet file memory error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a Glue Job script that converts JSON to Parquet and the script works fine, it's retrieving the files from S3 and converting the files to Parquet. These files that I am processing are between 1 - 1.5GB and it processes anywhere from 50 to 200 files a day. After running for a bit, I get either these two messages:

```
ValueError: Could not reserve memory block
Command failed with exit code 10
```

I'm using Worker Type G.2X with a maximum number of works of 50. I am not sure what I can do to not get this error message. Here is my script I created:

```
import sys 
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
from datetime import datetime
from urllib import parse
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr
import re
import boto3
import os
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['env_source_bucket', 'env_processed_bucket', 'env_curated_bucket', 'env_destination_json_folder', 'env_destination_par_folder', 'env_destination_err_folder'])

# Environment Variables
source_bucket = args['env_source_bucket']
processed_bucket = args['env_processed_bucket']
curated_bucket = args['env_curated_bucket']
destination_json_folder = args['env_destination_json_folder']
destination_par_folder = args['env_destination_par_folder']
destination_err_folder = args['env_destination_err_folder']

destination_par_folder_with_bucket = 's3://' + processed_bucket + '/' + destination_par_folder
destination_json_folder_with_bucket = 's3://' + curated_bucket + '/' + destination_json_folder

def get_date_from_file(sourcekey):
    date_file_created = sourcekey[sourcekey.rfind("/")+1:(sourcekey.rfind("/")+11)]
    date_file_created_conv =re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', date_file_created)

    try:
        final_date_file_created = datetime.strptime(date_file_created_conv.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    except Exception as error:
        file_path_with_out_agency_number =sourcekey[sourcekey.find("_")+1:(sourcekey.rfind("_"))]
        date_file_raw =file_path_with_out_agency_number[file_path_with_out_agency_number.rfind("_")+1:(file_path_with_out_agency_number.rfind("_")+9)]

        try:
            x = datetime.strptime(date_file_raw,'%Y%m%d')
            final_date_file_created=x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        except Exception as error:
            print('WARNING: Missing date in file name', error)
            final_date_file_created='9999-12-30'
    return final_date_file_created

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '.')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out
    
def main():
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket = curated_bucket, Prefix = destination_json_folder)
    
    for page in pages:
        for obj in page['Contents']:
            files = obj['Key']
            sourcekey = files
            json_file = os.path.basename(sourcekey).replace(' ', '+', 1)
            s3_json_location = destination_json_folder_with_bucket + json_file

            only_file_name = os.path.basename(s3_json_location)
            only_path_name = s3_json_location[:-(len(only_file_name))-1]
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(only_file_name)
            
            date_file_created = get_date_from_file(sourcekey)
            print('Date from file -> ', date_file_created)
            
            destination_par_folder_with_partition = str(destination_par_folder_with_bucket) + 'flowstartdate=' + str(date_file_created) +'/'

            try:
                dfs = wr.s3.read_json(path=[s3_json_location], lines=True, orient='records')
                # converting all datatypes to string
                dfs = dfs.astype(str)
                
                print('Writing the files to parquet...')
                wr.s3.to_parquet(df=dfs, path=destination_par_folder_with_partition + filename + '.parquet')
                print('Successfully converted to parquet')
                
                print('Deleting the file.....')
                s3.delete_object(Bucket=curated_bucket, Key=sourcekey)
                print('Successfully deleted the file -> ', json_file)
            except JSONDecodeError as e:
                print('Error =>', e)
                print('Not a proper json file')  
                copy_source = {'Bucket':source_bucket_name, 'Key':sourcekey}
                destination_err_file = destination_err_folder + 'flowstartdate=' + str(date_file_created) + '/' + json_file;
                s3.copy_object(CopySource = copy_source, Bucket = destination_bucket, Key = destination_err_file)
                print(f'Copying the error file -> {json_file} to the bucket -> {destination_bucket}')
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AWS Wrangler to read in the json file, I used Pandas read json and so far it's working

```
dfs = pd.read_json(s3_json_location, lines=True, orient='records')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).